# Need help passing defined C constants to asm instruction

Tags: c, assembly, macros, microcontroller, preprocessor

I have the following code in a C program for a ATmega microcontroller:

```
define sbi(port,bit) asm("SBI " #port "," #bit)
[...]
sbi(PORTB,1);
```

The problem is that the compiler does not recognize PORTB when it's processing the assembly code, despite being defined in an included header file. Is there a way to tell the precompiler to put the defined value of PORTB (0x1b) in the ASM instruction rather than the literal text PORTB? The assembly instruction works fine when I manually do this like so:

```
sbi(0x1b,1);
```

But for obvious reasons I'd like to be able to use PORTB and other defined names in my C code.

Please note, I'm only using this ASM macro for defined constants, not variables, so I don't need anything too fancy to bridge between my ASM macro and my C code. I just need the preprocessor to replace PORTB with 0x1b in the ASM string.

Comment: You are probably using GCC, but, when asking questions about compiler-specific features like `asm`, you should always specify which compiler you are using.

Comment: See the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html), in particular the bottom paragraph: _"If you want to stringize the result of expansion of a macro argument, you have to use two levels of macros."_ TL;DR: create a `#define str(x) #x` then use `asm("SBI " str(port) "," #bit)`

Comment: I'm currently using the XC8 C Compiler that comes with Microchip Studio. I'm not married to this compiler, however (it's just the default). I can switch to GCC if it results in a better outcome.

Answer (score 3):

You generally should not use stringification (the macro `#` operator) to construct strings for the `asm` construct. Instead, use the [extended `asm` syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm).

To put operands into assembly instructions, use that syntax with [*constraints*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints) that tell the compiler how it may give the operands to the instructions. For immediate operands, use `i`:

```
asm("SBI %[port], %[bit]"
    : // Output operands would be here.
    : // Input operands are here.
        [port] "i" (PORT),
        [bit]  "i" (1)
);
```

The `%[port]` in the instruction string is replaced by the operand named `port`. The `[port]` in the operand list later on says the name of that operand is `port`. Of course this matches `PORT` except for the case, but you can use other names.

The `"i"` says to use an immediate operand, which must have a compile-time constant value.

The `PORT` in `(PORT)` is an expression that gives the value to use for the operand. For example, you could also use `(PORT+1)`.

The `1` operand could be hard-coded, but the above shows how to keep it flexible.

For a default immediate operand with `i`, GCC and Clang include the punctuation that marks an immediate operand in assebmly code, such as `$` in some assemblers. If this is a problem for some reason, you can use `%c[port]` instead of `%[port]` to get the bare operand, and insert the `#` manually, as with:

```
asm("SBI #%c[port], #%c[bit]"
    : // Output operands would be here.
    : // Input operands are here.
        [port] "i" (PORT),
        [bit]  "i" (1)
);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get the following error: macro "asm" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1.

I'm currently using the XC8 C Compiler that comes with Microchip Studio.

Comment: @Michael: Did you try this asm syntax outside of a macro to see if it compiles, and if so to what asm?  If it's ok, then worry about making it a macro (all on one line is probably easiest, or use \ line continuation.)

Comment: I was finally able to switch to GCC for my compiler and configure it to automatically generate SBI & CBI instructions from native C code. I'm still learning this Microchip Studio software (I used to do all my programming on a Linux box), but now that the compiler is giving me what I want, I no longer need to insert my own assembly code. I still appreciate the help, however, so thank you!